# mongoose find() inside a foreach

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to find documents based on some conditions that are in a array
for example:

```
subscriptions=[
{teacher: 'john', student:'david' ,course:'math'},
{teacher: 'john', student:'david' ,course:'english'},
{teacher: 'matt', student:'max' ,course:'math'}]
```

I want to find in `Exam` collection where: teacher, student, and course is based on this array:

```
subscriptions.forEach(sub=>{
Exam.find({teacher:sub.teacer, student:sub.student, course:sub.course},(err,res)=>{})})
```

whoever, I can't call find inside a for loop, should I use `async` library? I think there is a better way for this query and I dont need a loop

Comment: what is your expected output with the example-data you provided?

Comment: You have a typo, maybe that was the cause of the problem: `teacher:sub.teacer`

Comment: @ninesalt the problem is with the logic, I didn't even write the code to test it. for loop is async but find it , and I don't have a callback for it

Comment: @PhilippSander the expected output is a array of Exams that have the appropriate conditions

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get all the documents matching one of your array entry :

```
const subscriptions = [{
    teacher: 'john',
    student: 'david',
    course: 'math',
  },
  {
    teacher: 'john',
    student: 'david',
    course: 'english',
  },
  {
    teacher: 'matt',
    student: 'max',
    course: 'math',
  },
];

Exam.find({
    $or: subscriptions,
  })
  .then((ret) => {
    // Deal with the data
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Deal with the error
  });
```

---

If you want to get the data in separated arrays :

```
const subscriptions = [{
    teacher: 'john',
    student: 'david',
    course: 'math',
  },
  {
    teacher: 'john',
    student: 'david',
    course: 'english',
  },
  {
    teacher: 'matt',
    student: 'max',
    course: 'math',
  },
];

Promise.all(subscriptions.map(x => Exam.find(x))
  .then(([
    find1,
    find2,
    find3,
  ]) => {
    // Deal with the data
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    // Deal with the error
  });
```

---

---

```
// Explaination of :

.then(([
  find1,
  find2,
  find3,
]) => {
  // Deal with the data
})


// This is the equivalent

.then((rets) => {
  const find1 = rets[0];
  const find2 = rets[1];
  const find3 = rets[2];

  // Deal with the data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should select using an or operator rather than in a loop:

```
Exam.find().or(subscriptions).then(docs => { 
/*logic here*/ 
})
.catch(error => { 
/*error logic here*/ 
})
```

Answer (score -1):

use [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#each)

```
app.get('/',function(req,res){ 
var examsArray= [];

async.each(subscriptions,function(sub,callback){
      Exam.find({teacher:sub.teacher,
                student:sub.student,
                course:sub.course},
             function(err,exams){
                 if(err) return callback(error);
                 if(!err && exams){ 
                     examsArray.push(exams);
                     return callback(exams);
                 }
            });
     },
     , function(err) {
         if (err) { res.json(err); }
         console.log("ALL FINISH");
         if(!err){ res.json(examsArray); }
      });
    });
 });
```